# Encountered error while trying to install package

Tags: python, c++

while downloading `pip install gpaw`

I faced this problem :

copying gpaw\xc\gllb\c_xc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gpaw\xc\gllb      copying gpaw\xc\gllb\nonlocalfunctional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gpaw\xc\gllb
copying gpaw\xc\gllb\nonlocalfunctionalfactory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gpaw\xc\gllb
copying gpaw\xc\gllb_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gpaw\xc\gllb
running build_ext
building '_gpaw' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\bmgs
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\xc
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=7 -DGPAW_NO_UNDERSCORE_CBLACS=1 -DGPAW_NO_UNDERSCORE_CSCALAPACK=1 -UNDEBUG -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcc_gpaw.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c_gpaw.obj -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -std=c99
cl : 명령줄 warning D9025 : '/DNDEBUG'을(를) '/UNDEBUG'(으)로 재정의 합니다.
cl : 명령줄 error D8021 : '/Wno-unknown-pragmas' 숫자 인수가 잘못되었습니다.
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> gpaw

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

I am using Python 3.9.7 win 10 pro.

I downloaded the visual studio C++ pack.

what should I do?

Comment: I'd recommend translating the errors to English, as they probably provide important information

Answer (score 0):

`gpaw` is not supported on Windows.  You can use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), or a Linux VM, but not straight Windows.